# Automorphism group of a free product

Tags: gr.group-theory, automorphism-groups

Suppose that $G$ and $H$ are groups (not isomorphic) and $G\ast H$ the free  product. Let $Aut(G)$, $Aut(H)$ be the automorphism groups of $G$ and $H$. What is $Aut(G\ast H)$ ?

Comment: Surely this depends on the particular $G$ and $H$...

Comment: It is certainly not a straightforward function of $\text{Aut}(G)$ and $\text{Aut}(H)$. For example, take $G = \mathbb{Z}_2, H = \mathbb{Z}_3$. Then $G \ast H \cong PSL_2(\mathbb{Z})$, whose automorphism group is, I imagine, $PGL_2(\mathbb{Z})$.

Comment: Consider the case $G=H=\mathbb{Z}$. Then we have $Aut(G)=Aut(H)=\mathbb{Z}_2$, but $G\ast H=F_2$, which has a very complicated automorphism group.

Comment: It's called "free product". It is also the amalgam (or amalgamated product, but not amalgamate) of the two groups over the trivial subgroup.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan, your example isn't a great one, since $\mathrm{Out}(\mathbb{Z}/2)=1$ and $\mathrm{Out}(\mathbb{Z}/3)=\mathrm{Out}(PSL_2(\mathbb{Z}))=\mathbb{Z}/2$, so in the *outer* automorphism group *does* in fact arise in a simple way from the outer automorphism groups of the factors.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is not an answer, but it's too long for a comment and makes an important point that I hope is useful.

It's not enough to think of your group just as some free product. To understand its automorphism group you need to think of it as a free product in a *canonical* way, and for this you need the Grushko decomposition.  Recall:

> **Grushko's decomposition theorem:** If $G$ is finitely generated then
>
> $G=G_1*\ldots* G_n*F_k$
>
> where each $G_i$ is freely indecomposable (ie isn't $\mathbb{Z}$ and doesn't split as a free product) and $F_k$ is free of rank $k$. Furthermore, the $G_i$ are determined up to conjugacy (and reordering), and $k$ is determined.

The key thing to notice here is that the $F_k$ factor is *not* determined up to conjugacy, and therefore if $k>0$ then there are complicated automorphisms that arise essentially from the different possible ways to choose $F_k$. However, the picture is relatively simple if $k=0$.

A modern reference on the (outer) automorphism groups of free products is [this](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0501288) nice paper of Guirardel and Levitt.

Comment: Excellent, thank you! Actually your answer is more then what i was hoping for !

Comment: In fact, even with only two non free factors, $A,B$ you have complicated automorphism called "partial conjugations" : let $b\in B$, then there exists an automorphism which fixes $B$ and conjugate $A$ to $bAb^{-1}$

Comment: @Thomas, well, it depends what you mean by 'complicated'.

Comment: It is an automorphism which is not inner, and does not come from  $Aut(A)$, $Aut(B)$, an analog of Dehn twist. In fact the automorphism group of $A*B$ is generated by such automorphisms, $Aut(A), Aut(B)$, and inner automorphisms....In the case of $A*Z$, you must add the automorphism which is $Id$ on $A$ and map $t$ to $ta$ if $t$ is the generator of $Z$. The general case is obtained by mixing these sorts of automorphisms...

Comment: @Thomas, on the contrary, it does 'come from ... $\mathrm{Aut}(B)$'.  More precisely, it's the composition of an inner automorphism of $B$ (which, as you rightly observe, gives you a non-trivial outer automorphism of the free product) with an inner automorphism of $A*B$.  I would classify such things as not 'complicated', though I concede that what one may find complicated is a matter of taste.   (But the definition I have in mind is that an automorphism is 'not complicated' if it fixes a point in the deformation space of Grushko decompositions.) ...

Comment: ... Anyway, as I tried to make clear, the point of my answer was not to give a complete description of the automorphism group (there are perfectly good references in the literature), but to point out that in order to give such a description, one should consider the Grushko decomposition, and not just the free splitting that one has in hand.

Comment: @HRW, but it does not if you have 3 factors $A*B*C*$ and you conjugate $A$, not $C by some $b$... They are analogs of Dehn twists. These animals generate the so called "Fuchs-Rabinowitz group", which has completely be describe in the 40's, I think. They are usefull to describe the mapping class group of connected sum in dim 3, where they play the role of Dehn twists.

Comment: @Thomas, I'm really not sure what point you're trying to make.  I stand by my assertion that, when $k=0$, the picture is 'relatively simple'.  You assert that the case of three free factors is 'complicated'. The upshot of this discussion doesn't seem very interesting except to conclude that what I think is 'relatively simple' you think is 'complicated'.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/31787/discussion-between-thomas-and-hjrw).

Answer (score 6):

The known reference is Fuchs-Rabinowitz (or Fouxe-Rabinowitz, Mat. Sbornik, 8 (1940), pp 265-276  and 9 (1941) 183-220. The papers are in Russian and German , see MR0003413 for a review. A more recent reference is McCullough Miller, 
Symmetric automorphisms of free products. Mem. Amer. Math. Soc. 122 (1996), no. 582, viii+97 pp.(MR1329943 )

Comment: Do you know if there exists a proof of Fouxe-Rabinowitz's description of the generators elsewhere in the literature?

Comment: Collins Zieschang, Rescuing the Whitehead method for free products.Math. Z. 185 (1984), no. 4, 487–504 gives a more precise result...than FR.

Comment: Thank you, I will take a look at the article.